# Need help Simple Eclipse script for android app

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm writing a simple app for my Bday to see how many people will come.

I need to assign an action to the button when every time I press it, it adds 1 to the final number of guests.
Button id is: "Button"
Final number of guests id is: "Number"

Could someone help me with the script for Eclipse? I know it is easy but I am stuck.

Comment: What script??? do you mean code???

Comment: Please show what you've tried to do so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just incrementing a local variable? If the button is declared in the Activity, just do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button button;

@Override
onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.Button );

    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v ) {
            Number++;
        }
    } );

}
}
```

Comment: Also what do you mean "script"?

Comment: You might want to add `setContentView(your_layout_with_the_button_with_id_Button);` before the `findViewById(R.id.Button)` line.

Comment: Hi Tyler, Thank you so much for answering. I'm still a bit stuck. May I send you my java script for more specific fixes?

Comment: When are you using JS in your Android app?